# Spring with SAML for http-artifact binding

Tags: spring, binding, frameworks, saml, opensaml

For sometime now i have been trying to find a solution to the SAML http-artifact binding :(.
I am using the OpenSAML  with spring . I am able to get it working with the http-post .  my requirement is http-artifact. ie. the after getting the artifact i need to fetch the assertion via a back end SAOP call. Could you please give me some sample configuration code  ? . Also please let me knw the if i need to make it work with the both SAML1 and SAML 2 . your help is greatly appreciated. thanks in advance.

Comment: I guess not many people use the opensaml with spring ? :(

Comment: http://git.springsource.org/~jtellier/spring-security/se-security-saml-ecp/trees/ae6c0d470c410bbee2fbd0b201cc45af9c267f76/spring-security-saml  is a good app for starters but its very complicated but it has all the binding . But i want a simple http artifact config settings.

Comment: OpenSAML with spring. Does this means that you use the Spring security SAML module?

Comment: no just plain spring and opensaml ...

Comment: could anyone please tell me atleast the different security policies available and how to implement a basic security model

Comment: just some simple security policy thats it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The artifact can be resolved using the ArtifactResolve class. This is sent to the artifact resolution service and the assertion is returned. Here is a OpenSAML example I wrote.

[Resolve artifact with opensaml](https://blog.samlsecurity.com/2011/02/resolve-artifact-with-opensaml.html)

Comment: Hi stefan I have been following ur blog and its great . I have already check your solution, But could you please provide me with the SAMLUtil class as well .I think others are also asking for it. it would be a great help. and thanks for the reply

Comment: This is not a comment really relevant to the question but as I have told the other people that asked the methods can be found here http://mylifewithjava.blogspot.no/2011/04/convenience-methods-for-opensaml.html

Comment: My mistake sorry ...you have been great help stefan . one small doubt if i had to put some security say some encryption and decryption in the given example how can i achieve it . and thanks in advance\

Comment: There are guides for this in the OpenSAML docs. https://wiki.shibboleth.net/confluence/display/OpenSAML/OSTwoUserManJavaXMLEncryption

Comment: Please flag the answer as correct if you thing it answers your question.